# Scanning similar numbers and putting them in diffrent arrays

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I have a txt file that looks like this

```
63001230 3 10
63001234 8 3
63000176 8 6
63001432 - 0
```

First 8 digit number I already stored. Now, I want to store second column(3 8 8 -) in one array and third column (10 3 6 0) in another array.

Do I do this with

```
fscanf(file,"%d %d %d", existingarray[i], array2[i], array3[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second array must be `char` to read `-`.
Also you must pass the addresses of the array elements to `fscanf()` like this:

```
int existingarray[LEN],array3[LEN];
char array2[LEN];
//...
fscanf(file,"%d %c %d", &existingarray[i], &array2[i], &array3[i]).
```